# How to chance Button Behavior Source from a different Class?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I want to show some png files for my dynamic python buttons so i used below structure, but it does not work . I want to change self.source = ''  at class MyButton(ButtonBehavior, Image): dynamically
from if conditions which are in def Over() that exist in  Programme  class.
In this way result of if conditions, my buttons source images will be different.
Could you please help me to fix this?
May be there is another solution for this.
When i tried this code it shows white boxes in my program and does not show any png file.

Thanks

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.metrics import dp
import requests
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image

class MyButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.source = '' # I blanked here i want to change here from a different class
       
class Programme(BoxLayout):

    mybutton = ObjectProperty(MyButton)
       
    def Over(self, s_image, screenmanager):
   
        for i in range(len(self.Today[0])):
           
            sonuc = Some calculations
           
            if sonuc < 2.50:
                self.mybutton.source = 'images/1.png' (How can i change self.source = ''  at class MyButton(ButtonBehavior, Image): from here?
            else:
                self.mybutton.source = 'images/2.png' (How can i change self.source = ''  at class MyButton(ButtonBehavior, Image): from here?
           
            box = BoxLayout(size_hint_y = None, height = dp(50))            
            ust_2_5 = mybutton(size_hint = (0.15, 1) )
            box.add_widget(ust_2_5)
            self.ids.gridsonuc.add_widget(box)
```

Comment: you could create minimal working code so we could copy and test it - and use it to create solution.

Comment: do you get error message when you run it in console/terminal? Maybe you have problem in different place.

Comment: if you set `self.source = ''` then it always shows white box. You have the same while box when you use directly `Image()` without `source`. Maybe `Over` is never executed and it can't set image. Or maybe `range(len(self.Today[0]))` is empty and it never execute `for`-loop. You could use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing.

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: Could you comment for my fix

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it :D But it is too strange!

Firts i added this. There is no code in KV file about Updown!

```
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior


class Updown(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    
  pass
```

Than i used this structure!

```
box = BoxLayout(size_hint_y = None, height = dp(50))
            sira = WrappedLabel(text = f'{i+1}', font_name = 'fonts/Lcd.ttf', font_size = dp(15), size_hint = (0.10, 1), halign='center' )
            evsahibi = WrappedLabel(text = f'{self.Today[0][i]}', font_name = 'Roboto', font_size = dp(15), size_hint = (0.225, 1), halign='center' )
            deplasman = WrappedLabel(text = f'{self.Today[1][i]}', font_name = 'Roboto', font_size = dp(15), size_hint = (0.225, 1), halign='center' )
            macbasigol = WrappedLabel(text = f'{sonuc}', font_name = 'fonts/Lcd.ttf', font_size = dp(15), size_hint = (0.15, 1), halign='center' )
            if sonuc < 2.50:
                ust_2_5 = Updown(size_hint = (0.15, 1), source = 'images/down.png')
                ust_3_5 = Updown(size_hint = (0.15, 1), source = 'images/down.png')
            elif sonuc >= 2.50 and sonuc < 3.50:
                ust_2_5 = Updown(size_hint = (0.15, 1), source = 'images/up.png')
                ust_3_5 = Updown(size_hint = (0.15, 1), source = 'images/down.png')
            else:
                ust_2_5 = Updown(size_hint = (0.15, 1), source = 'images/up.png')
                ust_3_5 = Updown(size_hint = (0.15, 1), source = 'images/up.png')
            box.add_widget(sira)
            box.add_widget(evsahibi)
            box.add_widget(deplasman)
            box.add_widget(macbasigol)
            box.add_widget(ust_2_5)
            box.add_widget(ust_3_5)
            self.ids.gridsonuc.add_widget(box)
```

result is:

[image]

Before this solution i tried below solution but not worked could you please comment for below?

Added

```
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior


class Updown(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    
  pass
```

KV file:

```
<Updown>:
    id: test123
    source: '' # blank
```

Example code

```
if sonuc < 2.50:
    self.ids.test123.source = 'images/1.png' (How can i change self.source = ''  at class MyButton(ButtonBehavior, Image): from here?
else:
     self.ids.test123.source = 'images/2.png' (How can i change self.source = ''  at class MyButton(ButtonBehavior, Image): from here?
           
box = BoxLayout(size_hint_y = None, height = dp(50))            
ust_2_5 = Updown(size_hint = (0.15, 1) )
box.add_widget(ust_2_5)
self.ids.gridsonuc.add_widget(box)
```

I got keyerror for test123!
I wanted to change source from ids of Updown Button behaviour but not worked
Could you comment please!